# Changing a label's text is not working properly on transparent widgets

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, pyqt6

This seems like a bug, but I wanted to confirm before reporting it.

I am trying to update a label's text on a transparent widget, but for some reason the previous text is partially visible (see screenshot below)

Did any one face this issue before? Is there any known workarounds?

System Specs: MacOS Monterey 12.0.1 and Python 3.10

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GcJfX.png)

```
from PyQt6 import QtWidgets, QtCore
from PyQt6.QtCore import QTimer
from PyQt6.QtGui import QFont
from PyQt6.QtWidgets import QLabel


def update_label():
    l1.setText("Bye!")
    window.repaint()


app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
window = QtWidgets.QWidget()
window.setAttribute(QtCore.Qt.WidgetAttribute.WA_TranslucentBackground)
window.setWindowFlag(QtCore.Qt.WindowType.FramelessWindowHint)
window.setFixedSize(800, 600)
font = QFont()
font.setPointSize(72)
l1 = QLabel(window)
l1.setText("Hello World")
l1.setFont(font)
l1.setStyleSheet("color:red")
window.show()
timer = QTimer()
timer.setInterval(10000)
timer.timeout.connect(update_label)
timer.start()
app.exec()
```

Comment: Qt (as much as other toolkits) has a long history of issues whenever a new macOS version pops out. It's not Qt's fault, as their devs work very hard to keep compatibility with lots of different platforms and versions, and Apple doesn't make it easy, as they're known for changing important core aspects sometimes breaking lots of backward-compatibility (their policy is, more or less, "we change it, the rest of the world has to adapt and upgrade, and we don't care"). Also, while Qt6 is now a year old, it's still under hard development, and while 6.2LTS has been released in september, they ->

Comment: -> obviously cannot keep up with OS versions that have different release timings. That said, first of all, ensure that you've the latest PyQt6 version (6.2.2 was released a couple of weeks ago), and, if you can, check whether your code properly works with PyQt5 or not. If the issue still arises, then you should submit a bug in their system: https://bugreports.qt.io by providing the example code and all relevant information. I also suggest you to try to set a proper [layout manager](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/layout.html) (as you always should) for the parent and add the label to it.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure it could be considered an answer, but I found a workaround.

Simply close then show the window again:

```
def update_label():
    window.close()
    window.show()
    l1.setText('Bye!')
```